# how to change all table td cells to tr rows

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td> A-1 </td>
       <td> A-2 </td>
       <td> A-3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> B-1 </td>
       <td> B-2 </td>
       <td> B-3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is something like this:

> A-1    A-2    A-3  
> B-1    B-2    B-3

And i want to change that like this in my CSS when the screen size is below 420px:

```
<table>
       <tr> <td> A-1 </td> </tr>
       <tr> <td> A-2 </td> </tr>
       <tr> <td> A-3 </td> </tr>
       <tr> <td> B-1 </td> </tr>
       <tr> <td> B-2 </td> </tr>
       <tr> <td> B-3 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

To be like this:

> A-1  
> A-2  
> A-3  
> B-1  
> B-2  
> B-3
>
> In one word : I want to have all of my cells in separated rows

Comment: does it need to be in a tabled format? its relatively simple to do otherwise.

Comment: @JohnKane what are the other ways?

Comment: This would give you a lot more control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define `display:block` to your **TD** .Write like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:420px){
    td{display:block}
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DQtfa/

Comment: +1, but what is this: `@media screen and (max-width:420px){`?

Comment: @sandeep It work fine in [http://jsfiddle.net/DQtfa/](http://jsfiddle.net/DQtfa/) but it don't work in my local site. I use twitter bootstrap!

Comment: @sandeep That works! I just misstyped an extra dot before td : 

**.td{display:block;}**

Comment: My requirement was reverse, I needed to make tr in same row instead. Your answer helped me to get insight, I did `tr { display: inline-block; }`

Thank you!